# Simple PHP/MySQL ACL System

Tags: php, mysql, acl

I have a simple ACL system in PHP and MYSQL started.  I need help finishing it though...

I have 2 Database tables shown below...

**user_link_permissions : Holds a record for every user, on every entity/link that permissions apply to...**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user_link_permissions`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_link_permissions` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `link_id` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `permission` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2055 ;
```

**intranet_links : Is basically the entity that the permission gives or revokes user access to**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `intranet_links`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `intranet_links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` text,
  `user_login` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_pw` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `sort_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `local_route` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `local_route` (`local_route`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34 ;
```

---

To save these permissions settings I have a matrix style grid like this below where each checkbox is a record in the user_link_permissions table...

[image]

---

I need help creating a simple ACL function in PHP which can check if a user has permission or not to view a link/entity based on the database results.

On page load I am thinking I can query the `user_link_permissions` DB table for all records with a matching user ID of the logged in user and store them to a session array variable.

A function could then use that array to check for a link/entity permission using that array value on the entity key.

I just can't visualize how it might look at the moment in PHP.

Any help please?

```
function aclCanAccess($user_id, $entity_id){


}


$entity_id = 123;
if(aclCanAccess(1, $entity_id){
    // yes user can see this item
}else{
    // NO user permission denied
}
```

Comment: What is an int(30)? What is an int (100)?and what is an int(2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will leave writing the code to you for fun.

Assume you are storing all the previously queried permissions in a variable called `$_SESSION['acl']`

Your ACL function should:

1. check the session if you already queried that entity
2. if it is not set, read it from the db

in short

```
function..... {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['acl'][$entity_id])) {
        $_SESSION['acl'][$entity_id] = query here to return to you if he has access or not
    }
    return $_SESSION['acl'][$entity_id];
}
```

You can also read the entire array when you log in the user. That might also be appropriate. In that case you should be able to just

```
return $_SESSION['acl'][$entity_id];
```

But I would then try and catch an exception in case it is not set.

Comment: I got it now.  I load in all permission records matching user ID and loop over them creating an array `$permissions[entity_id_here] = permission value` son on a page where I need the permission of `entity_id = 1` `$permissions[1]` will hold a value of `0` or `1` for that user on that permission item.  Ill select your answer to close this up and as it's another possible solution

Comment: Actually reading your answer it sounds like it is somewhat what I mentioned anyways so it's a valid answer! thanks  I am also using Laravel so on my DB query I can simply use `->remember(10)` on my query to have it auto-cached

Comment: I would still say use the session or some caching mechanism to do that. Read it once when you log in or read it when you access things but limit the number of hits to the DB.

Comment: I am rather sure that Laravel has some ACL included into it, Or you can find a bundle to add ACL easier, I would install such a bundle and see how it works, maybe just change the function that actually returns the permission. Also look into RBAC as after you implement it once you will never look back to something as simple as ACL.

Comment: Yes I am using Laravels caching mechanism on the DB query.  There are bundles available for ACL but everything seems overly complex compared to the system I built.  Also my system allows permissions on a per user, per entity level which most only work at something like a group level and not per user so what I have seems to be working pretty good and is simple and lightweight but I will look into this `RBAC` you mention.  thanks

Comment: Ahh you meant "Role-based access control" my system does that but my boss require per user permissions as well so the role/group level is just another layer in our ACL above the per users level

Comment: RBAC should allow you both, it all depends how you define the rules & permissions. From what you say you are using RBAC just calling it ACL. I use another way of showing the matrix in my application but it does almost the same thing as what you do.